# Easy way to merge files in Linux, based on line timestamp?

Tags: linux, merge

We currently have a process which grabs distinct log files off a remote system and places them all in a single consolidated file for analysis.

The lines are all of the form:

```
2023-02-08 20:39:32 Textual stuff goes here.
```

so the process is a rather simple:

```bash
cat source_log_file_* | sort > consolidated_log_file
```

Now this works fine for merging the individual files into a coherent, ordered, file but it has the problem that it also sorts lines *within* each of the source log files where they have the same timestamps). For example, the left side below is modified to the right side:

```
2023-02-08 20:39:32 First   ==>  2023-02-08 20:39:32 First
2023-02-08 20:39:32 Second  ==>  2023-02-08 20:39:32 Fourth
2023-02-08 20:39:32 Third   ==>  2023-02-08 20:39:32 Second
2023-02-08 20:39:32 Fourth  ==>  2023-02-08 20:39:32 Third
```

This makes analysis rather difficult as sequence within a source log file is changed.

I *could* temporarily insert a sequence number (per source file) between the timestamp and the text and remove it from the consolidated file but I was wondering if it were possible to do a merge of the files based on timestamp rather than a sort.

By that, I mean open every single source log file (which is *already* sorted correctly based on sequence) and, until they're all processed, grab the first line that has the earliest timestamp and add it to the consolidated file. This way, the order of lines is preserved for each source log file but the lines from the separate files are sequenced correctly.

I can write a program to do that if need be, but I was wondering if there was an easy way to do it with standard tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use just the timestamp as the sort key, not the whole line. Then use the `--stable` option to keep the lines in their original order if they have the same timestamp.

```
sort -k 1,2 --stable source_log_file_* > consolidated_log_file
```

Comment: Awesome, it's no longer reordering lines with WARNING/INFO after the timestamp to put warning last. It preserves the order from the original file.